# Image uploading using ion library in android studio

Tags: php, android

how to upload an image to server using API from android using ion library? I don't know much about ion library.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @Ashwin Valento [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412832/upload-image-with-ion-android-library) you need to do this.

```
ArrayList<Part> fileParts = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < salonPhotos.size(); i++) {
    Part part = new FilePart("image_name[" + i + "]",image_value[i]);
    fileParts.add(part);
}


Ion.with(getContext())
.load("POST", MY_POST_URL)
.setMultipartParameter("my_text_key", "my_text_value")
.setMultipartParameter("my_text_key_2", "my_text_value_2")
.addMultipartParts(fileParts);
```

Here the image is being sent as a part of multipart form data to the server. Or you could send the image in base64 format like [here.](https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2016/10/android-convert-image-base64-string-base64-string-image.html) It's pretty straight forward.

Comment: Is "salonPhotos" meant the name of the imageview?

Comment: its the arraylist of image files.

Answer (score 0):

My original answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43774689/3742798) which explains how you can upload multiple images.

If your requirement is to upload a single image, then you can do as

```
Ion.with(getContext())
.load("POST", MY_POST_URL)
.setMultipartFile("image", "image/png", new File("/sdcard/some_image.png"))
```